# Django Admin Panel Content Posting Error

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

While I was adding content for my django web site on admin panel,I get the error.After I added 10-15 content,site give the this error. "`The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.`"

I analysed nginx and uwsgi logs.

Nginx log contains to below line.

```
2012/06/02 22:02:53 [error] 5203#0: *602 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 92.10.214.1, server: server.com, request: "POST /admin/hdduyuru/duyurular/add/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:1235", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/admin/hdduyuru/duyurular/add/"
```

And uwsgi log contains to below line.

```
invalid request block size: 4169 (max 4096)...skip
```

I'm using below line to deploy my site on uwsgi+nginx

```
/usr/bin/uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:1245 --master --workers 5 --harakiri 30 --disable-logging --daemonize /tmp/daemonize.log --pidfile /tmp/pidfile.txt --vacuum --gid 500 --uid 500 --ini /home/uwsgi.ini
```

/home/uwsgi.in

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/home/
module=hdblog.wsgi:application
master=True
pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid
vacuum=True
max-requests=5000
daemonize=/tmp/hdblog.log
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like the request headers may have exceeded the default uwsgi maximum buffer size of 4k.  Try increasing the buffer size by adding `buffer-size=32768` to your `uwsgi.ini` file.

Comment: I used to -b 32768 and solved this problem.Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Why 32768? If that's bits, it's just 4096 bytes again.

Comment: @Oli - It's not bits. 32,768 because it's 32k, eight times larger than the default of 4k.

Comment: Okay so why 8 times larger? I'm just trying to work out the optimal value, so what are the benefits of going higher or lower (but still more than 4K)

Comment: @Oli - According to [uWSGI docs](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc), '_If you plan to receive big requests with a lot of headers you can increase this value upto 64k_'. I would just keep increasing it until you don't have any problems. The 'optimal value' is the lowest value at which no errors occur.

Comment: for the record the MAX value is 65535

Comment: @Oli , this is a little late, but thought I'd add this brief discussion I found which helped me with a similar problem:

http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2012-October/004878.html

I just decided to go with 32K straight up rather than play around with 8K, it's not worth my time to experiment with something that's a very transient problem on our system, only been a few hours since the fix but seems to be doing okay.